# Libgdx 3d particle error on initialization

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, game-engine, game-development, particles

I'm having a rendering issue for 3d particles created with the flame particle editor in libgdx.

I'm using a particle system to render 3d particles created with flame, I followed the tutorial in the libgdx' official site: [code taken from:](https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/3d/3d-particle-effects) , but when I try to render them, I get the following error:

```
Cannot invoke "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.particles.batches.ParticleBatch.draw(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.particles.renderers.ParticleControllerRenderData)" because "this.batch" is null
```

Here's my code:

```
    class MyGame : ApplicationAdapter(){
    //3d stuff
    lateinit var cam: PerspectiveCamera
    lateinit var camController: CameraInputController
    lateinit var modelBatch: ModelBatch
    lateinit var environment: Environment
    lateinit var model: Model
    lateinit var mb:ModelBuilder
    //lateinit var ground:ModelInstance

    lateinit var ecs:World
    //creating the bullet world
    lateinit var broadphase: btBroadphaseInterface
    lateinit var dynamicsWorld: btDynamicsWorld
    lateinit var constraintSolver: btConstraintSolver
    lateinit var collisionConfig: btCollisionConfiguration
    lateinit var dispatcher: btDispatcher
    lateinit var contactListener: MyContactListener
    //debug drawer
    lateinit var debugDrawer: DebugDrawer
    //particle effects
    lateinit var particleSystem:ParticleSystem
    lateinit var pointSpriteBatch:PointSpriteParticleBatch

    override fun create() {
        Bullet.init()
        //initializing 3d stuff
        mb = ModelBuilder()
        initializeWorld()
        initializeBullet()
        ecs= world {
            injectables {
                add(mb)
                add(modelBatch)
                add(cam)
                add(camController)
                add(environment)
                add(dynamicsWorld)
                add(debugDrawer)
                add(contactListener)
            }
            components {
                onAdd(BulletComponent, BulletComponent.onAdd)
                onRemove(BulletComponent, BulletComponent.onRemove)
            }
            systems {
                //the model system works just fine!
                add(ModelSystems())
                //this is going to be fun
                add(BulletSystem())
            }
        }
        with(ecs){//creating the ground
            mb.begin()
            //ok so for every model you create you giv it an id (makes everything more flexible)
            mb.node().id="ground"
            mb.part(
                "ground",
                GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                (VertexAttributes.Usage.Position or VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal).toLong(),
                Material(
                    ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED)
                )
            )
                .box(0f, 0f, 0f, 5f, 1f, 5f)
            model=mb.end()

            var motionState=MotionState(ModelInstance(model).transform)

            val ground=entity {
                //it+=ModelComponent(ModelInstance(model))
                it+=BulletComponent(motionState, btBoxShape(Vector3(2.5f, 0.5f, 2.5f)),0f)
            }

        }

    }

    private fun initializeBullet() {
        collisionConfig = btDefaultCollisionConfiguration()
        dispatcher = btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfig)
        broadphase = btDbvtBroadphase()
        //setting the dynamic world
        constraintSolver= btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver()
        dynamicsWorld= btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher,broadphase, constraintSolver, collisionConfig)
        dynamicsWorld.gravity= Vector3(0f, -1.8f, 0f)
        
        contactListener = MyContactListener()

        debugDrawer=DebugDrawer().apply {
            debugMode= btIDebugDraw.DebugDrawModes.DBG_DrawWireframe
        }
        dynamicsWorld.debugDrawer=debugDrawer
    }

    fun initializeWorld(){
        modelBatch = ModelBatch()
        environment = Environment()
        environment.set(ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f))
        environment.add(DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f))
        cam = PerspectiveCamera(
            67f, Gdx.graphics.width.toFloat(), Gdx.graphics.height
                .toFloat()
        )
        cam.position[3f, 7f] = 10f
        cam.lookAt(0f, 4f, 0f)
        cam.near = 1f
        cam.far = 300f
        cam.update()
        camController = CameraInputController(cam)
        Gdx.input.inputProcessor = camController
        //initializing particle effects
        particleSystem=ParticleSystem()
        pointSpriteBatch = PointSpriteParticleBatch()
        pointSpriteBatch.setCamera(cam)
        particleSystem.add(pointSpriteBatch)
        //adding the particle effect to an asset manager
        var assets=AssetManager()
        var loadParam=ParticleEffectLoader.ParticleEffectLoadParameter(particleSystem.batches)
        assets.load("myfirst3dparticles.pfx",
            ParticleEffect::class.java, loadParam)
        assets.finishLoading()
        //passing the particle effect from the asset manager to the particle system
        val originalEffect: ParticleEffect = assets.get("myfirst3dparticles.pfx")
// we cannot use the originalEffect, we must make a copy each time we create new particle effect
        val effect = originalEffect.copy()
        effect.init()
        effect.start() // optional: particle will begin playing immediately

        particleSystem.add(effect)

    }


    override fun render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        //always update the camera if you're gonna make changes to it
        //cam.update()
        camController.update()



        modelBatch.begin(cam)
        //modelBatch.render(ground, environment)
        //setting particles to be rendered
        particleSystem.update()
        particleSystem.begin()
        particleSystem.draw()
        particleSystem.end()
        modelBatch.render(particleSystem)
        

        ecs.update(Gdx.graphics.deltaTime)
        modelBatch.end()
    }
```

Comment: You seem to not have a batch initialized, did you call `particleSystem.add(insertYourBatchObjectHere)` before this is ran? To be of more assistance more code could be posted as well.

Comment: I posted the whole code so that it's more clear what's happening, ecs it's just an entity component system, and initialize bullet is being used for collision detection, so I don't think they're the issue.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)